# Searching for the MLO file on the Beaglebone Black

Tags: beagleboneblack

I have a Beaglebone Black industrial(BBBI), which I assume is very similar to the Beaglebone Black.

I wish to make the BBBI boot to microSD card by default, and I found this [guide](http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:Updating_The_Software#Image_For_Booting_From_microSD), which suggested to delete the `MLO` file from the boot partition. This has been mentioned in a few places based on Google, so I assume it is worth trying

With the intention of renaming the `MLO` file, I tried to locate the file using `$locate`, after booting without a microSD card, which presumably boots into Debain on the eMMC. This produces the following:

```
/opt/backup/uboot/MLO
/opt/source/pru-software-support-package/pru_cape/bin/MLO
/opt/source/pru-software-support-package/pru_cape/bin/MLO/beaglebone
/opt/source/pru-software-support-package/pru_cape/bin/MLO/beaglebone_black
/opt/source/pru-software-support-package/pru_cape/bin/MLO/beaglebone_black/MLO
/opt/source/pru-software-support-package/pru_cape/bin/MLO/beaglebone/MLO
```

I have double checked that `/boot` does not have `MLO`. Is anybody able to share where the MLO is, or did I missed something very obvious?

Alternatively, is there an easier way to boot from the microSD card without pressing the S2 button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Newer images put MLO outside the filesystems, directly at several "magic" offsets on the eMMC/SD-card. That's documented in the TRM for AM335x.

If you don't care about current eMMC contents, something like this will do the brute force job:

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=1M count=1` 
(make sure mmcblk**0** is the eMMC, not the SD card, it changes if you boot from SD and can be mmcblk**1** too)

It wipes out the first Megabyte of the eMMC with zeroes. So the partition table and other things are gone too. Essentially you get a blank eMMC.

If you want to be a bit more surgical, look at the [flashing script](https://github.com/RobertCNelson/boot-scripts/blob/master/tools/eMMC/init-eMMC-flasher-v3.sh) in `/opt/scripts`. Also `functions.sh` is interesting.

Note that MLO is also referred to as SPL.

Comment: Thanks! I would like to confirm that your dd step works

Comment: Are you referring to the the `/dev/mmcblk0boot0` and `/dev/mmcblk0boo1` ? i am curious how to see what's on these devices. they don't have a file system so they couldn't be mounted. are they each one bin dump of MLO ? also could they be "removed" so that the eMMC looks like SD card i.e a FAT partition and an ext part. ?

Comment: No, I was not referring to those. I don't think those are supported by the SoC. That's an eMMC feature in the MMCA/JDEC spec 4.3 for boot mode. Those are two additional 128kbyte storage areas. There is some switching logic. I never worked with those. Micron TN-29-18 seems to explain it too.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the uenv.txt file to load the image from the SDCARD always.

Comment: Any idea how this can be done?  What line should be modified, and how?